# Transistor Latching Momentary Switch Help

Tags: transistors, switches, toggle-switch, latching

[image]

Attached is a circuit for two "latching" transistor circuits using a momentary switch to toggle a relay. Switch 1/ Relay 1 works perfectly; toggles on/off as it should.

Switch 2/ Relay 2 ONLY turns ON. It will not toggle off.
Switch 2/ Relay 2 ALSO turns ON when toggling Switch 1 on for the first time.

This works great on the breadboard but I had a PCB built and it has the aforementioned bugs.

Does anyone know why this might be? I have checked and double checked that the breadboard matches the circuit. All component values are correct.

I can't tell what I'm missing.

Comment: "works great on the breadboard but I had a PCB built and it has the aforementioned bugs"  "I have checked and double checked that the breadboard matches the circuit"   Time to check if the PCB matches the schematic.

Comment: I used DipTrace and autorouter to draw the traces. Is there any way that there could have been a pseudo- voltage divider situation happen based on the order the power was fed in to the circuit?

Comment: Your circuit has memory, so "the order the power was fed in" can conceivably influence its state and then have a persistent effect.  But "pseudo voltage divider" is likely not a useful abstraction for solving your problem.  Rather, check that the voltages at each node are as expected on power-up (you can compare to the breadboard version), then that they are as expected when a button is depressed, then check after the button is released.  When you find when the behavior of the two physical implementations diverge, it'll help you find the problem.

Comment: Note that "DipTrace and autorouter to draw the traces" is concerned with the PCB layout as designed.  You need to check the actual physical PCBA.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful for troubleshooting!